# Como puedo generar el acceso a un recurso raw de forma dinámica en android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, recyclerview, android-recyclerview

Tengo en la carpeta raw varios recursos en forma de pistas mp3. Tengo un botón que al pulsarlo tiene que reproducir el recurso asociado, pero este recurso y este botón lo lee de un archivo json y lo carga en un recycler. El json me devuelve el nombre del archivo por ejemplo "audio1", pero para reproducirlo tiene que ser "R.raw.audio1". Si se pulsa el botón 2, tiene reproducir "audio2", y así, pero lo que no sé hacer es unir el R.raw. (que no viene en el json) a lo que lea del json (audio1)

Dejo el código erróneo, a ver si véis como solucionarlo:

```
int recurso=new Integer("R.raw."+mValues.get(position).getrUri());
//mValues.get(position).getrUri() devuelve un string con el nombre del recurso almacenado en raw
MainActivity.mp= MediaPlayer.create(c.getApplicationContext(), recurso);
```

Comment: Hola Dave, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto (solo la parte involucrada en tu problema, y de ser posible que se pueda ejecutar), mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo, es la siguiente (seguramente hay más y mejores):

Primero creamos la siguiente función:

```
public static int obtenerCancion(String nombreAudio, Class<?> c){
    Field field = null;
    int id = 0;
    try{
        field = c.getField(nombreAudio);
        try{
            id = field.getInt(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("ID", "obtenerId: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("FIELD", "obtenerId: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return id;
}
```

Lo que hacemos en esta función es recibir el nombre el audio en formato string y la clase. Para ello declaramos un field que nos permita obtener información.

Luego en tu onCreate:
Como yo no tengo un archivo json con los nombres simplemente cree un vector con dos nombres de audios. En tu caso lo obtienes de otra forma pero es lo mismo

```
    String[] sonidos = {"dog", "wolf"};
    final MediaPlayer[] mp = {null}; 
    btnEjemplo1.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mp[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), obtenerCancion(sonidos[0], R.raw.class)); //aquí utilizamos la función y le asignamos el nombre del sonido y la clase raw que es donde pertenece el/los audio/s
        mp[0].start(); //le damos a reproducir y listo
    });
    btnEjemplo2.setOnClickListener(view -> {
        mp[0] = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), obtenerCancion(sonidos[1], R.raw.class));
        mp[0].start();
    });
```

En este ejemplo uso varios botones para reproducir los sonidos, tu usas un RecyclerView por lo que la única diferencia es que no necesitas crear un vector de tu MediaPlayer. Espero te sirva

Comment: Mil gracias, me funcionó!!

Comment: Que bueno que te haya servido, no olvides aceptar la respuesta!